# Android oncharacteristicchanged sometimes not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a probleme with my bloetooth low energy code. My probleme is that sometimes the `oncharacteristicchanged` not called after 2-3 `writeCharacteristic`, sometimes `oncharacteristicchanged` called 2-3 times (**with the same answer**)

```
private Queue<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptorWriteQueue = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattDescriptor>();
private Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicWriteQueue = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
```

**Here is my gattcallback:**

```
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {         

    descriptorWriteQueue.remove();  //pop the item that we just finishing writing

    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        Logger.E( "Callback: Wrote GATT Descriptor successfully.");           
    }           
    else{
        Logger.E( "Callback: Error writing GATT Descriptor: " + status);
    }

    //if there is more to write, do it!
    if (descriptorWriteQueue.size() > 0)  mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptorWriteQueue.element());
    else if (characteristicWriteQueue.size() > 0) mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicWriteQueue.element());
}

public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,  int status) {

    characteristicWriteQueue.remove();


    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        //broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        Logger.E("onCharacteristicWrite success: " + status); 
    }
    else{
        Logger.E("onCharacteristicWrite error: " + status);
    }

    //if there is more to write, do it!
    if (characteristicWriteQueue.size() > 0) mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicWriteQueue.element());
    else if (descriptorWriteQueue.size() > 0)  mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptorWriteQueue.element());
}
```

**Here is how I write the characteristics & descriptors:**

```
public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
    //put the characteristic into the read queue        
    characteristicWriteQueue.add(c);
    //if there is only 1 item in the queue, then read it.  If more than 1, we handle asynchronously in the callback above
    //GIVE PRECEDENCE to descriptor writes.  They must all finish first.
    if ((characteristicWriteQueue.size() == 1) && (descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 0)) {
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(c);              
    }
}

public void writeGattDescriptor(BluetoothGattDescriptor d){
    //put the descriptor into the write queue
    descriptorWriteQueue.add(d);
    //if there is only 1 item in the queue, then write it.  If more than 1, we handle asynchronously in the callback above
    if ((descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 1) && (characteristicWriteQueue.size() == 0)) {   
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(d);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution? I have the same problem and cant find anything. Thanks!